# Create one Policy for Multiple Models?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel-permission package and permissions for handling authorization I have a problem:

I should add a permission to user but I also should check that user be a owner to can do that action so I want use Policies but the  problem is  when using Policies We should add a Policy for each of my models and the logic is the same I think It is very Bad idea.

now I have multiple option:

1- Create a Policy but use it for multiple models and I don't know How

2- Create a Custom Class and create something like policy

what option is better?

Comment: Can you show some code? Without seeing any code I'd suggest defining a custom middleware: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#defining-middleware

Answer (score 2):

1) [you can bind multiple models to the same policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#registering-policies):

```
protected $policies = [
    Model1::class => WildcardPolicy::class,
    Model2::class => WildcardPolicy::class,
    Model3::class => WildcardPolicy::class,
];
```

2) unclear what your exact goal is

Answer (score 0):

Your question very very good. I had not solve same problem too me. I think, your problem has not solving with Policy way. I think, The polices are used to between a content and it author owner privacy.

You can solving with action / permission based way that check on middleware layer.

My recommanded solution scenario following;

You can checking logged user has access current action in user_roles table via middleware, or get all access action list and store in session of logged user.

The stored data are may be similar to;

```
$user = ['accessible_resources' => [
   'product' => ['index','show'],
   'news'    => ['index','show','edit','store','create','update','destroy']
];
```

I hope my solution helps to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
.....
use App\Models\Policies\WildcardPolicy;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
....
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        Model::class => WildcardPolicy::class,
    ];
.....
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just create your policy and register it in auth service provider class..

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
/**
 * The policy mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $policies = [
    'App\Admin' => 'App\Policies\AdminPolicy',
];
```

then in your models that use that policy just refer to the policy name like this

```
$this->authorize('desire method', Admin::class);
```